# Selecting a Record twice in order of created_at and updated_at

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to select a record twice on the basis of a two fields from mysql table.

for example my table have the following data:

```
 name,   created_at,  updated_at
"Baran", "2013-09-10 23:56:56", "2013-10-10 23:00:00"
```

I want a result set in descending order:

```
name,date
Baran,"2013-10-10 23:00:00"
Baran,"2013-09-10 23:56:56"
```

is it possible or not if yes then please advice how can i achieve this?

Comment: You shouldn't want that. Make two queries or process the result set twice on the app layer.

Comment: can you please give me suggestion how can i do at app layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(SELECT name, created_at as [date] FROM mytable)
  UNION all
(SELECT name, updated_at as [date] FROM mytable)
  ORDER BY name, [date] desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select your records as usual and create the "duplicates" in Ruby:

```
User.all.flat_map { |user|
  [
    {name: user.name, date: user.created_at},
    {name: user.name, date: user.updated_at}
  ]
}
#=> [{:name=>"Baran", :date=>"2013-09-10 23:56:56"}, {:name=>"Baran", :date=>"2013-10-10 23:00:00"}]
```